# gtm-http-fetcher modify HTTP Headers

Tags: http, http-headers, request

I didn't know if anyone here has had experience with the gtm-http-fetcher provided by [google](http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2010/09/http-fetcher-class-for-mac-os-x-and-ios.html). I am specifically looking to modify the HTTP headers in a request. Any help or examples would be appreciated.

-Pat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you supply the request to be fetched, you can specify the headers in the request as well. For example,

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"MyApp" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
[fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
              didFinishSelector:@selector(fetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
```